# Monitoring PWM Solar System

Tags: power, solar-cell, esp8266, voltage-monitor

I want to try and make a power monitoring system for an off-grid solar system using a micro-controller (esp8266). I started by monitoring the battery voltage (using a voltage divider and an ADS1115) and the current between the battery and the PWM charge controller using an ACS Hall effect current sensor.
I connected the battery ground to the ESP ground to measure the battery voltage.
Next step is to measure the current and voltage of the panel. Firstly, I thought to do the same thing with the panel (common ground panel-battery-ESP and current sensor), but then I disassembled the PWM charge controller and noticed the panel and battery positive terminal is actually connected directly to the battery positive terminal.

1. What will be the next step to measure the voltage of the solar panel? Or should I change the whole method?
2. Is there a way to isolate the micro-controller circuitry from the solar power circuitry to measure the voltage and amperage of battery and solar wires?

This is what it looks like now -

[image]

Would love any other suggestions!
Thanks

Comment: What hardware do you use? Did you design it/put it together on your own? A battery txpically requires some charge circuitry, it seems there is none in your setup... what kind of battery do you use? Please add the information to the question.

Comment: There is a solar charge controller, it's a 12v AGM battery, added drawing